# VS2012 including win32 and local rpc.h header breaking build (and VS2010 works fine)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, makefile, winsock2

I'm updating a project that was building with Visual Studio 2010 to build with VS2012. I am having issues with #includes using VS2012: I tracked it down to a local header in my project, RPC.h, being included because WinSock2.h indirectly includes win32 rpc.h (which matches my local file, including it). This worked fine in VS2010 and the makefiles are identical, the only difference is compiler.

To reproduce I created two files, one titled rpc.h which includes a missing header (and the first file does not explicitly include the local rpc.h).

TCPChannel.cc:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
namespace foobar {
}
```

RPC.h:

```
#ifndef __INCLUDED_RPC_H
#define __INCLUDED_RPC_H
// intentionally does not exist
#include <breakme.h>
#endif
```

Compile with "cl -c TCPChannel.cc" and it fails because the breakme.h does not exist (the setup is more complex than a missing header, but it suffices as an example).

I found that if I define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN, the win32 headers will not attempt to include rpc.h. Also I found that if I edit "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\Unknwnbase.h", and change "#include <rpc.h>" to an aboslute path, that works too.

Is there another solution to this, such as a compiler flag? I'd like to avoid adding WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN, and avoid editing system headers.

Comment: You could rename your version of rpc.h?

Comment: Great suggestion. That's my preference but the impact is too high. I'm likely left with having to use lean&mean, and this question is my last effort before doing that. I'm not a win32 wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I found no alternative. From the OP: I modified the makefiles to define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN, which doesn't #include rpc.h, fixing my issue.

If I needed lean&mean, the only good work around would be to rename the file.